# H264 Parsing seq_parameter_set_data : DefaultScalingMatrix4x4Flag, DefaultScalingMatrix8x8Flag

Tags: h.264

I try to parse H265 seq_parameter_data from an  RBSP  data... I use the reference from http://www-ee.uta.edu/Dip/Courses/EE5359/H.264%20Standard2007.pdf .

It shows how to parse  at page 40.

But the pseudo-algorithms use data structures such as **ScalingList4x4[ ]**,  **ScalingMatrix4x4Flag[ ]** etc... What are they? Are they constant tables or we fill them? Anybody has knowlegde about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to parse parameter sets (I assume this from your previous questions), you don't need these structures. You just need to skip certain amount of bits in order to skip the tables in full and move on to the values of your interest.